# Snap-based apps freeze after suspend

Tags: suspend, snap, freeze

I have a laptop running 20.04 (though I saw this on 19.04 as well on the same computer). I have three snap-based apps: Slack, VSCode and now Chromium. For each of these apps, and none others that I know of, every time I wake up from suspend, the snap apps are frozen.

They often peg the CPU at 100% until I kill them. The windows display and pain, but the application does not respond in any way. When I kill and restart, it opens back up fine. Not sure how to debug this or where one might report it.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if Chromium might be the common thread here since Slack and VSCode are Electron apps.

Comment: I uninstalled VSCode from Snap and reinstalled it from dpkg and it observes the same behavior. So I do think it's electron based apps.